# Debugging ofstream.(C++)

Tags: c++, debugging, ofstream

I need to create a debugging ofstream, which has the functionality as follows:

```
#define DEBUG true

int main() {
    debug << "Hello World\n";
}
```

The output in the above case should be:`Hello World`

And for the following code-

```
#define DEBUG false

int main() {
    debug << "Hello World\n";
}
```

The output should be **empty**.
Any suggestions how I should proceed.

Comment: Good luck, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Till now I have found the following solution: If I require the output to be processed then in the preamble section if I add `#define debug 0 && cout` I get the suitable output. I timed the program no delay which is a good thing. And on the same end if I replace it with `#define debug cout` I will obviously get the output shown on the screen. But I wanted to know whether there is a more general solution to it. This seems rather a hack than a solution.

Comment: The main drawbacks of defining  `debug` entity as a condition is that It doesn`t behave like a stream: `void print(std::ostream&); print(debug);` doesn't work. Inside interesting expressions it may also cause surprising results. On the other hand, using a condition is the only way to inhibit evaluation of the subexpressions being formatted. For example, the solution I posted has the semantic behaviour asked for in the question but it does evaluate the subexpressions.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Are you happy now?

Comment: No, you still haven't asked a question.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your question, you wish for a separate debugging stream (in contrast to `std::cout` and `std:cerr`).
You could accomplish this by making a "null stream" that simply eats everything and does nothing.

If your compiler is clever enough then it should even remove most of this in the end.

```
class NullStream {};

template<typename T>
NullStream& operator<<(NullStream& s, T const &) { return s; }

NullStream& operator<<(NullStream& s, std::ostream&(std::ostream&)) { return s; }
```

Now based on your macro you decide whether to use the `NullStream` or an actual `ostringstream`.

```
#if DEBUG
std::ostringstream debug;
#else
NullStream debug;
#endif
```

Testing it like this:

```
debug << "Hello World\n";
debug << 12345 << "\n";
debug << "Test" << std::endl;

#if DEBUG
std::cout << "Debug:" << std::endl;
std::cout << debug.str() << std::endl;
#endif
```

If `DEBUG` is not `0` then that would yield:

> Debug:
>
> Hello World
>
> 12345
>
> Test

Note that `NullStream` doesn't have any of `std::ostream`'s functionality per se, so another solution could be to derive from `std::ostream` and discard any input it receives.

Comment: Better to make `debug` `std::cerr`

Comment: @BoundaryImposition True. However I could gather from OP's question, that he/she wanted a separate stream. But I do agree.

Answer (score 0):

With your usage I think `debug` needs to be macro as there is no other way to pick up the value of `DEBUG`. A simple definition would be this:

```
#define debug (debugstream << enable<DEBUG>)
extern std::ostream debugstream;
template <bool Enable>
std::ostream& enable(std::ostream& out) {
    if (Enable) {
        out.clear();
    }
    else {
        out.setstate(std::ios_base::badbit);
    }
    return out;
}
std::ostream debugstream(std::cout.rdbuf()); // probably defined in a separate translation unit
```

The trick here is to enable/disable printing of the output using the stream's starte: no output is to be produced (by correctly written output operators) when the stream isn't in good state, I.e., if either `std::ios_base::failbit` or `std::ios_base::badbit` is set. This behaviour could be forced by setting/unsetting the stream buffer instead using `rdbuf()`.